# Excel - Choose non-adjacent parts of the array

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have five basic entries in A1 to E1 and one additional entry in F1. The formula I am trying to type in G1 is:

```
=CONCATENATE(LARGE(A1:D1,1),LARGE(A1:D1,2),LARGE(A1:D1,3),LARGE(A1:D1,4),F1)
```

For the next column H1, I'm trying to type the same formula, but the range is not supposed to be *A1, B1, C1, D1* any more, but *A1, B1, C1, E1*.

I dont know how to choose the n-th largest number of these five entries: *A1, B1, C1, E1, F1*.

I guess the first formula does not reflect what I am trying to do either, so what is the approach needed here?

Comment: Perhaps you could give a little more context to your question to help us understand **why** you want to achieve this? It's not entirely clear at all what you're trying to do, or what the problem is, so some example data and expected results would be helpful as well.

Comment: The main purpose to be achieved here is enumerating the possible card combinations. For instance the Texas Holdem hand, consisting of two hole cards and the five board cards. In order to calculate the highest hand for the current board, we use 0 hole cards, 1 hole card, 2 hole cards. With 0 cards, the task is easy. With 1 hole card, I need to replace boards 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th card with the Hole card 1.  At the same time, I need to sort the new hands (4 board and 1 hole card comb) to be sorted by ascending ranks and that where the LARGE function kicks in.

Comment: Ok, interesting. So given 5 cells containing values representing the board cards and 2 more cells containing values representing the player hole cards, you want to enumerate the 21 possible combinations of 5 cards from those 7? This would probably be a better way to phrase the question, rather than abstracting it. Does each card in the 52 card deck have a unique numeric value then, hence your usage of `LARGE`?

Comment: You are absolutely right. Each card has a numeric value 1 to 52, hence the usage of LARGE function. I could of course, enlist Board and Hole cards , like b1,b2,b3,b4,h1 and then b1,b2,b3,h1,b5 and so on, but the usual Excel would run out of recources and cannot handle it, thus I need a "shortcuts" and choose Large numbers of each array in ascending order to determine the hands' strenghth.